# Minimum Size of "R" Byte Code File?

Tags: r, minify, bytecode

I'd like to compile a `.Rc` file from an `R` source file so as to minimize its size.  Examining the `.Rc` binary generated I see a lot of stuff that is not necessary in a stripped down executable.  Of course, the names of libraries and string literals must be there, but unless one is going to be doing symbolic debugging, other symbol names are not necessary.  Also, some of them looked duplicated.

I see no compiler options to restrict things like symbol tables or otherwise minimize the size of the `.Rc` binary.

Are there other tools/libraries for doing this?  Perhaps `R` source code minifiers, etc. that might be used in conjunction with the compiler?